# holomorphic funktion is a polynomial

Tags: polynomials, holomorphic-functions

Let $f:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ be holomorphic. If we have $|f(z)|\leq|z|^n$ for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and all $z\in\mathbb{C}$, then $f$ is a polynomial.

I tried to apply Liouville's theorem but it does not help.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: No two "truly distinct" holomorphic functions can dominate one another. Hint: Consider the function $ g(z) = |f(z)|/|z|^n $. Can you prove that this function extends to an entire function?

Comment: Your function is really holomorphic in $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$? I wonder because the absolute value is not holomorphic. Maybe I can instead show that the funktion $g:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ with $g(z)=f(z)/z^n$ if $z\neq 0$ and $g(0)=f'(0)$ is a entire function which is bounded by 1. But that I can show. So we know that $g$ is constant, so $f(z)=cz^n$ for some $c\in\mathbb{C}$. Is that right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$|f(z)|\leq|z|^n$ implies $f(0)=0$.

Writing $f(z)=z^m g(z)$ with $g(0)\ne0$ implies $m \ge n$ and so $|z^{m-n}g(z)| \le 1$.

Now apply  Liouville's theorem.

Comment: How $|f(z)|\leq |z|^n$ implies $f(0)=0$? Is it also true if $n=1$?

Comment: @Quintic, just evaluate both sides at $z=0$. It does not work for $n=0$, but then you can apply Liouville directly to $f$.

Comment: Ok got it. Again , One more doubt $g$ is entire right? How?

Comment: @Quintic, from the Taylor series of $f$.

Answer (score 1):

Even true if the the condition is $|f(z)|\le C|z|^n$ for $|z|\ge R>0$. Let be $P_n$ the $n$th degree Taylor polynomial of $f$ at zero and consider $f-P_n$.